# N-Tier-Entity-Framework: 'GeneratedTextTransformation.ProjectUtility' does not contain a definition for 'ResolveProjectPath'

Tags: entity-framework, t4, n-tier-architecture

When I upgraded to the newest beta (in order to get the fixes in the generator for some inheritance issues allegedly resolved per [this question](http://ntieref.codeplex.com/discussions/547276)), I received 2 new errors at the same line in the T4 when trying to generate the classes:

> Error 9   Compiling transformation:
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingA3EC3BD3E5F228A9BC1C929F13763FE3AE36C19F432A59FEB1DDE5D0F681EB7C29852716DDA78FEF727C80DDC6674538B07CA98B354C4948632A3F2150F25ADA.GeneratedTextTransformation.ProjectUtility'
>   does not contain a definition for 'ResolveProjectPath'

and

> Error 10  Compiling transformation:
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingA3EC3BD3E5F228A9BC1C929F13763FE3AE36C19F432A59FEB1DDE5D0F681EB7C29852716DDA78FEF727C80DDC6674538B07CA98B354C4948632A3F2150F25ADA.GeneratedTextTransformation.T4Context'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'GetFullPath'

The error occurs in (project path)\T4\NTierEF.NTierEntityGenerator.CS.ttinclude

Is there something in T4 that I need to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Should've seen this before, but the answer is on their codeplex discussions page:

https://ntieref.codeplex.com/discussions/559965

The solution is to install the beta extension (which is not yet available on the Visual Studio gallery)